# Does adding navigation to presentation slides help the audience?

Tags: presentation-design

I'm creating a presentation template and I'm thinking of placing a little navigation on one side of the page to show viewers where they are in the presentation and whats left.

Does this make sense?

Comment: Hi Shoppyonline, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. I get the impression that your question would be a better fit for http://ux.stackexchange.com/, I'll ask the mods here to look into it. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid convention when it comes to slides. Lynda.com has a great presentation training for this. Think Steve Jobs, one word on a slide. The slides shouldn't be the bulk of the information, it should be the centering for the topic. If you wanted to report your company had a $5B sales increase you shouldn't do it like this:

Sales in 2014: ^$5,000,000,000

Most extreme example like this:

5

The talk should be the focus and the message the point. When you reveal your slide you can say, "I want to show you a number...It represents Billions in new volume"

Comment: Thanks tongsau. This very true. I'll give Lynda.com a look.

Answer (score 2):

This would depend on how the presentation is being navigated and who is controlling it.  From a visual perspective on a projector navigation may serve no purpose if you're the one controlling it.  A presentation slide show should only focus on what the current view point is targeting and adding a navigation would results in people always looking at it..

If your presentation is technical or one that someone may consider as boring I would imagine that the only thing someone may take away from it is "oh...  10 more slides left".

The content would also play a factor.  If your presentation is very large and sub-level topics than it might be a helpful reminder.